# What are the Best Practices for Android Tools Locations?

Tags: android, eclipse, java, adt

As we all know, a lot of things need to be installed before being able to create Android apps using Eclipse.

I ended up with the various pieces in the places noted below; if I "had it all to do over again," I would not necessarily place them in th same spots. Is there a "preferred method" for where these various tools should be installed?

```
Eclipse = C:\Users\Clay\Downloads\eclipse\eclipse
ADT = C:\Users\Clay\Downloads\eclipse\eclipse\plugins
JDK = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01
JRE = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
ADK = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

...Why I have both a "Program Files" and a "Program Files (x86)" folder I don't know, but I'm wondering if this mixing and matching might be problematic.

Comment: The reason you have a "Program Files (x86)" folder is because you're running a 64-bit version of Windows. As for a "preferred method" - I just download and install wherever looks logical in my warped mind. As long as eclipse can find everything, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But why two different ones - both a generic/vanilla AND a x86?

Comment: For backward compatibility - the same reason Windows NT v3.1 (back in the early 1990s - yes, I'm that old) had a Windows\System folder and a Windows\System32 folder. The System folder was for 16-bit Windows apps  - Windows NT apps (properley written) would use System32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the folder structure that you are using is fairly good. This is how I put things around. It try to put development tools/sdks at the root directory as compared to program files. Exception to this is Java which when installed actually installs itself in `Program Files`.

Say my root is `C:` and i use `tools-install` as the base folder, this how the directory structure looks

```
Eclipse = C:\tools-install\eclipse
ADT = <installed by eclipse so goes in Eclipse dir>
JDK/JRE = C:\Program Files\Java
(One thing to note though
 I set windows `JAVA_HOME` to `c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_01`
 to avoid the `space` in the path)
ADK = C:\tools-install\android-sdk
```

And the reason you have x86 folder is that you are running 64-bit version of windows.
NOTE: The reason for keeping Java in Program files is that it is easy to update when new version of java arives. I just need to update the `JAVA_HOME` and not move around files (as I have seen people copying `Java` folder to the root to avoid `space` in path issue).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of it is down to personal preference and, of course, the system you're using. I develop on Ubuntu and MacOS at home and Windows 7 at work. All three are completely different and I don't give a hoot so long as they work!

For the record, the sdk on my windows install is: `c:\Android` while on Linux it's: `~/Development/android-sdk-linux_x86`

I don't do OCD so on another install, it would probably be completely different ;)

If you can develop on Linux I think you'll find it much smoother. My Windows install is pretty  clunky and unreliable. A colleague (who is a big Win7 fan) has similar problems.